# VHDL comparing non-constant part of std_logic_vector to zeros

Tags: vhdl

Suppose I have a vector :

```
action_complete: in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)
```

How do I compare (inside the if statement) if PART of the vector is all zeros, where the comparison range depends on J (integer)? The integer is being changed inside the same process (state machine working with clock), but in other state.

Example code of what I want to do:

```
when s1 =>
    J<=J+1;
when s2 =>
    if action_complete(J-1 downto 0)=('all zeros') then ..
```

Comment: you can't use `others` but you can specify a range. `if action_complete(J-1 downto 0)=(j - 1 downto 0 => '0' ) then ..`

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm